# Why put custom action does not work in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

A put custom action approve was added to our rails 3.1.3 app in sourcing controller for updating 3 parameters. Custom route was added in routes.rb and link_to was called with :method => :put. However the parameters are not reset by the 'approve'.

Here is the link_to in sourcing index.html.erb:

```
<% @sourcings.each do |src| %>
...
<%= link_to 'Approve', approve_project_sourcing_path(@project, src), :method => :put if need_approve?(src) %>
<% end >
```

need_approve? is a method defined in sourcings controller to see if the sourcing needs to be approved.

Here is the rake routes output for approve:

```
approve_project_sourcing PUT    /projects/:project_id/sourcings/:id/approve(.:format)                                      {:action=>"approve", :controller=>"sourcings"}
```

Here is the approve in sourcing controller:

```
  def approve

    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @sourcing = @project.sourcings.find(params[:id]) 
    if vp_eng?
        @sourcing.update_attributes!(:approved_by_vp_eng => true, :approve_vp_eng_id => session[:user_id],
                                    :approve_date_vp_eng => Time.now, :as => :role_update)

      elsif ceo?
        @sourcing.update_attributes(:approved_by_ceo => true, :approve_ceo_id => session[:user_id],
                                    :approve_date_ceo => Time.now, :as => :role_update) 
    end
    redirect_to project_sourcing_path(@project, @sourcing)   

  end
```

Is anything we missed in the code above? Thanks so much.

Comment: Which part of the above is not working, exactly? What error or unexcpected behavior do you get?

Comment: You provide us many unnecessary code, but not provide what methods `vp_eng?` and `ceo?` are

Comment: @sourcing.update_attributes does not work. It was executed, but the :approved_by_vp_eng was not reset.

Comment: vp_eng? and ceo? were just as it says. It means if you are vp engineering and ceo, then you can execute the code within.

Comment: if it was executed, why are you asking about the put action?  If it was executed, then the put action worked

Comment: Put is for update and here requires a update. I am pretty sure the @sourcing.update_attributes was executed but could not figure out why the approved_by_vp_eng was not set to true.

Comment: If your server log shows that the request was handled by the `approve` action, I suggest you take the `routes` stuff out of your question, because it takes up a lot of space and is not helpful. Some things to add that might help: 1. Some of the server log info for the request, in particular what parameters are being received. 2. A bit of the Sourcing model's code, in particular any validations or before filters that are defined for it.

Comment: No error or message in log file for 'approve'. I assume the code for approve was executed without error.

Comment: Tried to use individual assignment to update 3 attributes and it worked. The controller and view code here should work. However the problem may be with attr_accessible in sourcing model which does not render the 3 attributes accessible in custom action approve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way to call update_attributes. With hash parameters, the correct syntax is :

```
@sourcing.update_attributes({:approved_by_vp_eng => true, :approve_vp_eng_id => session[:user_id],:approve_date_vp_eng => Time.now}, :as => :role_update)
```

A brace bracket is needed for the hash parameters.